# How to build a swipable UI for medium size (7") tablet web-app

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a web-app that will be used on a specific size tablet (3.5"x6").  I've worked with cell phone UI in the past, and primarily with desktops, but I have no experience with touch and tablets specifically.

I'm attaching a basic wireframe of the app.  It will be used during practice rounds in golf events by marshals (people stationary at every tee), to indicate which players are present at which hole so the spectators can easily find them.

This is the 3rd time we are actually building this app, but first time for a tablet.

I would like to have a fixed position div with half the alphabet on each size of the screen for easily narrowing down the players (I'm guessing implementing that would be pretty easy with AngularJS or jQuery).  The main part of the interface would be taken by two columns, the column on the left would have a toggle between selecting players coming up from a prior hole, or all players in the event. The column on the right would display players added to this hole.  I'd like the UX to work similar to the Gmail app on Android.  Swipe the player name to the right to add him to the Here column, and display an Undo button in that place.  Swipe left on the player in the Here column to remove from the list if necessary.

What would be the best framework to use and how would it help me achieve this? https://material.angularjs.org/ looks very promising, but I have no experience with it.  Maybe Bootstrap, AnglularJS UI or similar, that would help me easily create this?  My biggest challenge is creating the touch responsive div, while keeping the rest of the divs in their fixed positions.

Any suggestions on how to get this UI implemented?

[image]

Comment: *"Is there a framework like Bootstrap, AnglularJS UI or similar, that would help me easily create this?"* Probably.

Comment: if you are familiar with angular and bootstrap you should look into http://ionicframework.com/

Comment: What I really meant to ask, is how would I accomplish this in one of those frameworks, and which one might be the best?  In particular the biggest challenge I see is making  the All Event Players div swipable while the rest remain on screen.  Thanks

Comment: Angular has a module (ngTouch) which provides touch and gesture support (e.g. ng-swipe-left and ng-swipe-right).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how familiar you are with front-end development, but those are both great frameworks you've listed. Angular does more functionality and is reserved for single page apps usually. Bootstrap is just a styling framework to make front-end html coding simpler for the dev, and it's quite powerful.

If you were interested in doing this yourself, you would need to know the basics of responsive web design and read more on bootstrap. There are ways to position the divs for example, the sidebars should be positioned absolutely and the inner would be relative.

By positioning absolutely, its based on the screen size, not the containers, while relative positioning is based on the containers they're in.

If you're looking for help, www.basecodeconsulting.com offers services to create SPA's using angular. Also, check out this responsive angular app I made http://steveorrichio.com/games/w4w/#/ which is just a demo. Is this something you are looking for?